# How to share a folder from Files app on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can share a file from any application with my own application just by adding proper **document type** to my application .plist file. For example "public.image" document type enables images sharing.

But how can I share a folder from Files app with my application? I see that a folder also can be shared:

[image: folder sharing from Files app]

If to press "Share" then one can see that there are several apps which accept this folder as a sharing source. But my application is not in this list: it can accept single files but not folders. I have to note that this folder contains only files which are accepted by my application.

How to enable iOS application to accept folders using "Share" from Files app?

Comment: There is a ```public.directory``` UTI that may work for this. Just as you need to define the UTI type to import some file type (or packages = directories) I suppose you need to define a directory type as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is absolutely correct.